# Conditon on $|z|$ for which $\left(1+\frac{|z|}{n+1}+\frac{|z|^2}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{|z|^3}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} \dots\right)\le 2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Is it possible by elementary means to derive a bound on the modulus of $z $ for which we have that
>
> $$\left(1+\frac{|z|}{n+1}+\frac{|z|^2}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{|z|^3}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} \dots\right)\le 2$$?

By elementary means I mean methods from the usual exposition of (comples) series. If you should use it I may also say that I take the exponential function $\exp(z) $ to be defined by the convergent power series $\sum_{n=0 } ^{\infty } \frac {z^n } {n!} $.

Much grateful!

Comment: How good a bound do you need? The left hand side is $\leqslant \frac{n+1}{n+1 - \lvert z\rvert}$ using a geometric series as a majorant.

Comment: Okey you mean that for $|z|<n+1$ the series on the left converges to a limit $\le \frac {n+1 } {n+1 -|z| } $ and then if we consider $\frac {n+1 } {n+1 -|z| } \le 2 $  we get a bound $|z| \le \frac {n+1 } {2 } $? That would be sufficient!

Comment: Right. You can get it a bit larger, but the difference is only significant for small $n$. ($n =0$ gives $\log 2$ instead of $1/2$, for larger $n$ the value $(n+1)/2$ is closer to optimal.)